# After centering, interactions' effects got reversed. It was not fixed by reversing the dependent variable. What should I do?

Tags: regression, interaction, centering

In a binary logistic regression, I centered all the independent variables (binaries, continuous, dependent, independent, all [I have 5 IVs: three binary and two ordinal]). Multicollineariy was eliminated. But all the effects got reversed. I could manually fix the report (by switching every + to a minus and vice versa in beta values) and in odds ratios, by dividing 1 by each odds ratio. But I didn't know if Wald values remained the same?

So I reversed the zeros and ones of the dependent variable in order to simultaneously reverse again all the once-reversed betas (and fix them). Ok IV betas are now fixed. However, their interactions remain in the opposite direction! It seems that the interactions' directions depend on the IVs, and have apparently nothing to do with the dependent variable.

I think I should temporarily reverse all the signs of the centered IVs so the beta signs for the interactions (and their odds ratios) get what should be. But in that case, the betas for the main variables would be again reversed!

But I don't know if it is valid? Can I rely on such a model, in which the signs of betas are correct for the interactions, but reversed for main variables, Or a model in which main variables are correct but interactions are reversed?

Perhaps I should reverse centered IVs together with the DV, in the hopes that betas get fixed for both IVs and their interactions.

Do you have any solutions in mind? I would appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitely *not* manually reverse *any* of the betas; further, reversing either the DV or the IV does *not* change the meaning of your regressions.

If there was collinearity in the original regression, then *those* beta values are suspect; the new ones are likely correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear peter. You mean all those changes in directions of betas were due to removal of multicollinearity? But the sign reversal for interaction betas happened to All the interactions. Any interaction which was positive before centering has now become negative and vice versa. So I thought it is likely an artifact. Especially since those initial ones make much more sense than these reversed ones.

Comment: Once I removed multicollinearity by pinpointing and removing problematic interactions (all with VIFs > 10 or correlations > 0.4 with some other variables) (but not by centering). There remained a model in which some interactions existed. The beta direction of those remaining interactions were inverse of the same interactions in the new centered model. So perhaps that initial model was not actually free of multicollinearity...

Comment: Each model asks a different question, so it's not surprising they give different answers. If there was substantial collinearity in the initial model, that model should not be used as a comparison - one common effect of collinearity is reversal of the signs on coefficients.

Comment: Many thanks :) can we instead use bivariate correlation coefficients as a reference for beta directions? For example my Spearman coefficient showed that the effect of a variable was seen only in the "treatment" groups but not in the control groups. So I guessed there could be an interaction between treatment and that variable in a way that treatment sensitizes people to that variable. 

I wonder can I use such bivariate findings as references?

Comment: If so, that bivariate coefficient is pointing to some positive interaction between treatment and that variable. However, the new model is showing the opposite (it computes a negative beta for the interaction of treatment and that variable). [And I have difficulty discussing that inconsistent finding seen between the multivariate model and bivariate correlations]

Comment: No, you can't do that. The correlations do not control for other variables; adding variables can, indeed, change the signs of other coefficients, as can interactions.

Comment: Dear Peter, I came to an answer, which I would like to share. I checked the interaction betas and compared them one by one in the two models: before and after centering main variables. It appeared that the interaction betas in the new model are exactly the same as those in the model before centering. Their values do not show any smallest changes. The only difference is that the new interactions are negated.

Comment: So it became clear to me that the culprit is some errors in centering or maybe the effect of centering on reversal of IVs, on which interactions are based. I mean it is an artifact, but it is not for sure changes due to exclusion of multicollinearity. Because if the multicollinearity was the case, we should expect at least some micro changes in the beta values of the interactions, I think.

Comment: (and by not any smallest micro-changes, I mean that the beta, its SE, and Wald value are all exactly the same between the two models. Only the second set (after centering) is all negated).

Comment: I suppose it's possible that the code you used for centering reversed the item.